# How to create a modeless text-editing dialog in Flutter like Cut/Copy/Paste?

Tags: flutter, dart, modeless, modeless-dialog

The Flutter TextField has a really nice modeless dialog that appears above the field and stays visible even when the view is scrolled:

[image]

I need to create something very similar for when the user taps in a TextField (not when they select characters, which is when the copy-paste dialog appears). I created one using a Stack but quickly ran into trouble because the dialog was outside the pick box of the TextField so taps weren't detected by the GestureDetector (I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60788538/flutter-gesturedetector-not-working-inside-stack-with-textfield) the issue here). A workaround posted in a couple spots was to code a custom OverlayContainer but I just notice it doesn't scroll with the TextField.

Is there a widget I'm overlooking that makes modeless dialogs easier?